# Doubt about conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have a doubt about conditional probability.

Suppose I know $P^X, P^Y$ that are (fixed) distribution function of random variables $X, Y$.

To which conditions is $P(X|Y$) restricted to?

**Example**

$X \sim Binomial(10, \frac 13)$, $Y \sim Binomial(12, \frac 12)$.

Let $P(X = k | Y = m) = f(k, m)$.

I cannot choose $f(k, m)$ freely. For example, if I set $f(k, k) = 1 \ \ \forall \ k$, then this implies $X = Y$ (doesn't it?) 
But then again $X$ and $Y$ have different distribution function so it cannot be that $X=Y$.

I'm a little confuse in this regard, please help me understand better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints on $f$ defined by $f(k,m)=P(X=k|Y=m)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ defined by $p(k)=P(X=k)$ and $q(m)=P(Y=m)$ are that, for every $(k,m)$, $$f(k,m)\geqslant0,\qquad\sum_jf(k,j)q(j)=p(k),\qquad\sum_if(i,m)=1.$$ The set $C(p,q)$ of solutions $f$ is convex and non empty since $f:(k,m)\mapsto p(k)$ is always a solution.

The determination of $C(p,q)$ for some given distributions $p$ and $q$ is a nontrivial task, which is equivalent, at least when $q(m)\gt0$ for every $m$, to the determination of the *couplings* of $p$ and $q$. These are the probability measures $c$ such that, for every $(k,m)$, $$\sum_jc(k,j)=p(k),\qquad\sum_ic(i,m)=q(m).$$ Obviously, the passage from $c$ to $f$ reads $$c(k,m)=f(k,m)q(m).$$
Thus, perusing some classical references on the subject of *coupling* seems mandatory to anybody interested in this question.

Comment: As usual this is an amazing answer. Thank you very much. Do you happen to know a good paper that explains it? I will try to understand this better, even if I think I'm still not fully prepared for the task

Comment: There are freely available lecture notes on coupling all over the internet, you may have a try at Lindvall, *Lectures on the coupling method*.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is, by definition, the function
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}\ni (A,y)\mapsto \pi(A\mid y)
$$
satisfying the following three properties: 1) $y\mapsto \pi(A\mid y)$ is Borel measurable for all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, 2) $A\mapsto \pi(A\mid y)$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and 3)
$$
P(X\in A,Y\in B)=\int_B \pi(A\mid y) P_Y(\mathrm dy)
$$
for all $A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. These three properties uniquely determines the conditional distribution which is often denoted by $P(X\in \cdot\mid Y=\cdot)$.

**Exercise**: Show that when $Y$ is discrete then
$$
\pi(A\mid y)=
\begin{cases}
P(X\in A\mid Y=y),\quad &\text{if }\, P(Y=y)>0,\\
\mathbf{1}_A(0),&\text{if }\,P(Y=y)=0
\end{cases}
$$
is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$.

Comment: For the exercise, I've done the latter two things, but I'm having trouble showing that it is measurable (well, let's say that I don't have the faintest idea on how to do that, as I've never did an exercise like it. Basically all I know is that if it is continuos then it is borel measurable)
As for the answer, I have upvoted it because it is clear and helps my understanding but I don't think it answers my question fully, as it suppose that one knows $P(X \in A, Y \in B)$; I am interested in *how* $X$ and $Y$ can be related, given only $P^X, P^Y$.